# print calendar vertically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to print calendar vertically like this

```
1  8  15 22 29
2  9  16 23 30
3  10 17 24 31
4  11 18 25 
5  12 19 26
6  13 20 27
7  14 21 28
```

I tried below code

```
var x = 1;
var $tbodyTr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
for(var i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
   if(x == 7) {
       x = 1;
       $tbodyTr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
   } 
   $tbodyTd = $('<td>',{html: i}).appendTo($tbodyTr);
   x++;
}
```

But it prints horizontally.

```js
var $table = $('<table>',{'class': 'table-calendar table table-hover text-center table-calendar'});
var $tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo($table);
var x = 1;
var $tbodyTr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
for(var i = 1; i <= 31; i++){

 if(x == 7) {
  x = 1;
  $tbodyTr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
 } 
 $tbodyTd = $('<td>',{html: i}).appendTo($tbodyTr);
 x++;
} 
$('.table-responsive').html($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">

</div>
```

Looking for help, want vertical output.

Comment: Do you always want to print in 6 columns?

Comment: @Martin yes it is fix

Comment: In your first output you have only 5 comments. Which is it, 5 or 6?

Comment: @Martin i am not getting you. can you please explain me properly?

Comment: @Martin output i want it have 5 columns. and output which i am currently getting it has 6 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you can build the column values using their ordinal positions.

As this is for a calendar you can assert that a grid of 6*6 cells (or 7*5 in your example) is enough to fit all 31 days in, no matter where the starting position is. As such you can use two loops and calculate the day number based on the current row/col, like this

```js
var $table = $('<table>', {
  'class': 'table-calendar table table-hover text-center table-calendar'
}).appendTo('.table-responsive');
var $tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo($table);
var rowCount = 7, colCount = 5;

var html = '';
for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  for (var col = 0; col < colCount; col++) {
    var day = (row + 1) + (col * rowCount);
    if (day < 32) 
      html += `<td>${day}</td>`;
  } 
  html += '</tr>';
}
$tbody.append(html);
```

```css
td { padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive"></div>
```

This logic can then be easily tweaked to move the starting position based on day of week and also the number of days in the given month.

Comment: But as I have some special requirement I want output vertically. not horizontal. as i am expecting.

Comment: My bad, got the col/row in the calculation the wrong way around :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list the values in ascendcing order vertically, you need to calculate which value belongs in which cell.

To achieve this I have created the concept of rows and columns in the below snippet.

You can modify the `var columns = 5` to change the number of columns to whichever you wish.

```js
var $table = $('<table>',{'class': 'table-calendar table table-hover text-center table-calendar'});
var $tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo($table);
var x = 1;
var $tbodyTr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);

var columns = 5;
var target = 31;
var rows = Math.round((target - (target % columns)) / columns);
if (target % columns > 0)
  rows++;

// Rows
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  // Columns
  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    var nextNo = i + 1 + j * rows;
    if (nextNo <= target)
      $tbodyTd = $('<td>',{html: nextNo}).appendTo($tbodyTr);
  }
  $tbodyTr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
}

$('.table-responsive').html($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive"></div>
```

Output:

```
1   8   15  22  29
2   9   16  23  30
3   10  17  24  31
4   11  18  25
5   12  19  26
6   13  20  27
7   14  21  28
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :) really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is really very much appreciated. but logic is quite tough for me.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt: single loop, no products:

```js
var $table = $('<table>', {
  'class': 'table-calendar table table-hover text-center table-calendar'
});
var $tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo($table);
var x = 1;
var $tbodyTr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
for (var i = 1;; i += 7) {
  if (i > 31) {
    i = ++x;
    $tbodyTr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
  }
  if (x > 7) break;
  $tbodyTd = $('<td>', {
    html: i
  }).appendTo($tbodyTr);
}
$('.table-responsive').html($table);
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my answer to this because it uses less code but supports weekdays:

```js
const offset = 3; // weekday offset of 1st
const days = 31; // day count of month

const rows = new Array(7).fill().map(() => [""]);

for (let day = 1; day <= days; day++) {
  let n = day + offset - 1;
  rows[n % 7][Math.floor(n / 7)] = day;
}

const $tbody = $('.calendar tbody').eq(0);

$tbody.html(rows.map(row => $('<tr>').append(row.map(day => $('<td>').text(day)))));
```

```css
.calendar {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.calendar td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}

.calendar tr:nth-child(6), .calendar tr:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="calendar">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```